# reg Angular multi-dimensional and dynamic arrays

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and trying to achieve dynamic/multi-dimensional arrays in angular. I am attaching the code below:

app.component.ts code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormArray, FormGroup, AbstractControl }  from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'gmr';
    phaseForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
        console.log(1);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("In ngonit");
        this.phaseForm = this._fb.group({
          userName: [''],
          phaseExecutions: this._fb.group({
            PRE: this._fb.array([this.addPhase()])
          }) 
        });
        console.log(this.phaseForm);
    }

    addPhase() {
        console.log(22);
        return this._fb.group({
          phaseType: [''],
          phaseValue: ['']
        });
    }

    get phaseArray() {     
        const control = <FormArray>this.phaseForm.get('phaseExecutions')['controls'].get('PRE');
        console.log("value "+control);
        return control;
    }

    addMorePhase() {
        this.phaseArray.push(this.addPhase());
    }

    onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.phaseForm.value);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for app.component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="phaseForm" novalidate">    
    <input formControlName="userName" type="text" class="form-control">
    <h2>Add the phases</h2>    
    PRE Phase:
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" (click)="addMorePhase()">Add Pre-Phase</button>  
    <div class="row" formArrayName="PRE">
        <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let phase of phaseArray.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
            <div>
                <label class="col-sm-3">Phase type:</label>
                <input class="col-sm-3" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="phaseType">
                <label class="col-sm-3">Phase value:</label>
                <input class="col-sm-3" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="phaseValue">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Basically i want to add PRE phaseexecution dynamically and to start with already adding one PRE phaseexecution.

If i am trying to run this code i am getting the below error:

```
 AppComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'PRE'
    at _throwError (forms.js:1775)
    at setUpFormContainer (forms.js:1757)
    at     FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addFormArray (forms.js:4548)
    at FormArrayName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormArrayName.ngOnInit (forms.js:4762)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9243)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10507)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10469)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11102)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11062)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:6)
    View_AppComponent_0 @ AppComponent.html:2
    proxyClass @ compiler.js:10173
    push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:11306
    push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1719
    (anonymous) @ core.js:4578
    push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
    push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
    push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:3779
    push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:4578
      push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef._loadComponent @ core.js:4605
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.bootstrap @   core.js:4547
    (anonymous) @ core.js:4350
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef._moduleDoBootstrap  @ core.js:4350
(anonymous) @ core.js:4316
    push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:3820
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387  
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:872
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:3811
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:962
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4345
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
AppComponent.html:2 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 8, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_AppComponent_0 @ AppComponent.html:2
proxyClass @ compiler.js:10173
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:11306
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1724
(anonymous) @ core.js:4578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:3779
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:4578
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef._loadComponent @ core.js:4605
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.bootstrap @ core.js:4547
(anonymous) @ core.js:4350
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef._moduleDoBootstrap @ core.js:4350
(anonymous) @ core.js:4316
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:3820
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
(anonymous) @ zone.js:872
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:3811
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:962
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4345
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
core.js:3121 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
AppComponent.html:6 ERROR TypeError: this.phaseForm.get(...).controls.get is not a function
    at AppComponent.get [as phaseArray] (app.component.ts:41)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:7)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11054)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10451)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10692)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10634)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10457)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:11022)
    at ViewRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:8838)
View_AppComponent_0 @ AppComponent.html:6
proxyClass @ compiler.js:10173
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:11306
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1719
(anonymous) @ core.js:4578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:3779
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:4578
(anonymous) @ core.js:4462
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:3820
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:3734
next @ core.js:4462
schedulerFn @ core.js:3551
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3535
checkStable @ core.js:3789
onHasTask @ core.js:3833
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:441
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:461
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:285
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:962
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4345
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
AppComponent.html:6 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 17, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_AppComponent_0 @ AppComponent.html:6
proxyClass @ compiler.js:10173
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:11306
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1724
(anonymous) @ core.js:4578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:3779
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:4578
(anonymous) @ core.js:4462
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:3820
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:3734
next @ core.js:4462
schedulerFn @ core.js:3551
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3535
checkStable @ core.js:3789
onHasTask @ core.js:3833
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:441
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:461
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:285
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:962
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4345
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:76
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
    (anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

Why it will fail at line number 2 as shown in the error. looks very strange to me.
Any inputs or directions will be great help.

Thanks in advance.
Rishu

Comment: Check to see if me answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `formArrayName` without a parent `formGroupName`. Remember that `PRE` is a part of the `phaseExecutions` `FormGroup`. So you'll have to add a wrapping div with `formGroupName="phaseExecutions"` on it.

```
<form [formGroup]="phaseForm">
    <input formControlName="userName" type="text" class="form-control">
  <div formGroupName="phaseExecutions">
    <h2>Add the phases</h2>    
    PRE Phase:
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" (click)="addMorePhase()">Add Pre-Phase</button>  
    <div class="row" formArrayName="PRE">
      <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let phase of phaseArray.controls; let i=index;" [formGroupName]="i">
        <div>
          <label class="col-sm-3">Phase type:</label>
          <input class="col-sm-3" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="phaseType">
          <label class="col-sm-3">Phase value:</label>
          <input class="col-sm-3" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="phaseValue">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-eg-with-multidimentional-phase-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and making the things clear for me. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: did that..i was not sure how to do that :)... i have clicked the tick mark next to your answer... also i have raised another question on this itself..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453590/dynamic-addition-of-controls-in-angular-4    if you have time can you pls look intot this..i am sure you can definately give me some pointers/directions..

Comment: What a coincidence, I was actually working on that question itself :D. I'll update with an answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" formArrayName="PRE">
```

Should be

```
<div class="row" formArrayName="phaseForm.PRE">
```