# Dynamic Addition of Controls in Angular 4

Tags: angular

In this example, I have created a small form where I can add dynamic controls by clicking the "Add Pre-Phase" button.

After adding few pre phases I will choose phase type and in case the value selected is `EMS` then one extra control (`phaseType1`) should be added for that row only and other rows shouldn't change.

I am using the below logic and it doesn't work. Can you pls help me with your suggestions/pointers:

app.component.ts code snippet:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormArray, FormGroup, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  phaseForm: FormGroup; 
  selectedValue: string;
  emsSelected: boolean = false;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("In ngonit");
    this.phaseForm = this._fb.group({
      userName: [''],
      phaseExecutions: this._fb.group({
        PRE: this._fb.array([this.addPhase()])
      }) 
    });   
    this.selectedValue=""; 
  }

  addPhase(){
    console.log(22);
    return this._fb.group({
      phaseType: [''],
      phaseValue: [''],
      phaseValue1: ['']
    });
  }

  get phaseArray(){     
    const control = <FormArray>(<FormGroup>this.phaseForm.get('phaseExecutions')).get('PRE');    
    return control;
  }

  addMorePhase(){   
    this.phaseArray.push(this.addPhase());
  } 

  onChange(val,index: number){
    console.log("emsSelected Value is "+this.emsSelected);
    if (val === 'EMS'){
      console.log("EMS");
      this.emsSelected=true;
      this.phaseArray.at(index).patchValue({
      phaseType: ['EMS'],
      phaseValue: [''],
      phaseValue1: ['']
      })
    } else {
      this.emsSelected=false;
    }

    console.log("selected value is "+val +" and index is " + index);
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.phaseForm.value);
  }
}
```

code snippet of app.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="phaseForm" class="xx" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-1">Username:</label>
    <input formControlName="userName" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-3">
  </div>
  <div formGroupName="phaseExecutions">
    <h2>Add the phases</h2>
    PRE Phase:
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" (click)="addMorePhase()">Add Pre-Phase</button>
    <div formArrayName="PRE">
      <div *ngFor="let phase of phaseArray.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="row">
          <label class="col-sm-2">Phase type:</label>
          <label class="col-sm-1"></label>
          <label class="col-sm-2">Phase value:</label>
          <div *ngIf="emsSelected">
            <label class="col-sm-1"></label>
            <label class="col-sm-2">Phase value1:</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <select class="form-control col-sm-2" formControlName="phaseType" (change)="onChange($event.target.value,i)">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="EMS">EMS</option>
            <option value="SQL">SQL</option>
            <option value="Linux">Linux</option>
          </select>
          <label class="col-sm-1"></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-2" formControlName="phaseValue">
          <div *ngIf="emsSelected">
            <label class="col-sm-1"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-2" formControlName="phaseValue1">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I've added an answer. I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the methods like [**`addControl()`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addcontrol) and [**`removeControl()`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#removecontrol) on a [**`FormGroup`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#formgroup) instance.

This is how your `onChange` method is going to look like in that case:

```
onChange(val, index: number) {
  if (val === 'EMS') {
    (<FormGroup>this.phaseArray.at(index))
      .addControl('phaseValue1', this._fb.control([]));
  } else {
    (<FormGroup>this.phaseArray.at(index))
      .removeControl('phaseValue1');
  }
}
```

You will also have to remove the `phaseValue1` field to be added to the `FormGroup` by default since this will now be dynamically added or removed based on the value of the select field for that particular group.

```
addPhase() {
  return this._fb.group({
    phaseType: [''],
    phaseValue: ['']
  });
}
```

Finally, in the template, you can instead of using `*ngIf="emsSelected"`, you will have to create a method that tells whether the `FormGroup` in the `FormArray` at a particular index has a `FormControl` for `phaseValue1`. To achieve that you can define a method in your Component Class:

```
hasPhaseValue1At(index) {
  return (<FormGroup>this.phaseArray.at(index))
    .get('phaseValue1') ? true : false;
}
```

And then use it in your template:

```
<div *ngIf="hasPhaseValue1At(i)">
  <label class="col-sm-1"></label>  
  <input 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control col-sm-2" 
    formControlName="phaseValue1">
</div>
```

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-add-remove-controls-from-form-group-of-form-array?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: awesome @SiddAjmera... its working as expected..last question: any idea why the alignment is not proper whenever extra control e.g Phase value1 is getting added. It always appears small even though the class used is col-md-2 inside row class..still it is not coming in a row.. any thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Neither am I a css expert. I'm afraid you'll have to figure that out on your own.